# Script executes differently if run from udev

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, udev

I'm having an issue with a script that seems really weird; it appears to stop executing prematurely when run from udev, but not when I run it manually from the command line. I've tried troubleshooting it with the `set -x` and when I run it from the command line everything gets executed as expected. However, when it gets run from udev, it stops prematurely after a certain point.

Part of the issue, I think, is that it's hard to debug the script when it's run by udev. I've tried putting in `logger` statements, but they basically just tell me the same thing (it stops prematurely).

Do you see anything that pops out that would be causing this issue?

---

The script(s) can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/erichschroeter/3671e8d33405f0c07766). One note about them, they are intended for an embedded system. When run manually from the command line, the command I run is:

```
./product.sh -b update /dev/sda1
```

The udev rule that runs the script is:

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd?1", RUN+="/usr/sbin/product.sh -b update /dev/%k"
```

The script appears to stop at lines [195](https://gist.github.com/erichschroeter/3671e8d33405f0c07766#file-product-sh-L195) or [197](https://gist.github.com/erichschroeter/3671e8d33405f0c07766#file-product-sh-L197) in `product.sh`. I've noticed that if I comment out lines [22](https://gist.github.com/erichschroeter/3671e8d33405f0c07766#file-product-manifest-sh-L22) and [28](https://gist.github.com/erichschroeter/3671e8d33405f0c07766#file-product-manifest-sh-L28) in `product-manifest.sh` everything runs as expected when run by udev and manually on command line.

Comment: You need to use full, explicit paths for the executables - and to verify that the `find`, `xargs` and `md5sum` commands are  definitely available to you at the time you run the script.

Comment: I changed the `find`, `xargs`, `md5sum`, and the other commands (for safe measure) to their absolute paths, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: And did you verify that they're definitely available? Like `for c in find xargs md5sum; do [ -x /sbin/"$c" ] || ! break; done && /sbin/find ... | /sbin/xargs /sbin/md5sum`? Also, `udev` typically runs in a different [mount context](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sharedsubtree.txt) than what you may be used to. `umount anything` is usually a bad idea in a script run by `udev` especially because many `udev` rules are applied concurrently. If `find` searches a path which disappears while it does it will be a problem. Instead you should be calling up another `udev` rule.

Comment: Oh wait, I get it: `mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt/boot; find /mnt -type f | xargs md5sum`. That's your problem - you want an `&&` between them, I think. Are you quite certain that you're not actually working from the partition you're mounting when you do? You need to explore the mount state at the time the script runs - is it run from initramfs *(as I assume)*? And is there - at the time it runs - actually a dev called mmcwhatever available to mount? Is the `/mnt/boot` path possibly the one into which the initramfs might actually try to `switch_root` into eventually?

Comment: The system is not running from an initramfs. There is always a dev called mmcblk0p1 (there's also a mmcblk0p2) because it's specified in my kernel config; it's an on-board SD card. The `/mnt/boot` path is just a temporary mount point I can mount the partition that contains the boot files. The only purpose of mounting the boot partition is to list the files in the manifest.

Comment: Then it beats me, man. I still think it could have something to do with mount namespaces or mount trees, and I maintain that doing `mount` and `umount` from `udev` *(which can/should do the mounts itself each in a rule all its own)* is an altogether bad idea, but more specifically... i dunno.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. I'll delve deeper into the mount namespaces...wasn't aware of that.

Comment: One more thought, though. Is it possible that the mount you do actually triggers another, conflicting `udev` rule? Perhaps one related to fsck or similar? Or perhaps the mount you do occurs *while* an fsck is running maybe? Or is the fs driver module definitely already loaded? It's these kinds of things that *(not counting namespaces)* can make `udev` tricky - especially where mounts are concerned. It's designed to do as much as possible in parallel and so synchronous actions - of the kind you would typically use in shell scripts - are often unreliable where devices are involved.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I figured out the issue. I think the issue is the result of line [157](https://gist.github.com/erichschroeter/3671e8d33405f0c07766#file-product-sh-L157) where I'm redirecting the output to a file; that file happens to be a mounted USB drive. I'm guessing the redirecting is done concurrently, and when `product-manifest.sh` is complete the script continues, eventually leading to umounting the USB drive before the concurrent write to the USB drive is complete. And when the umount occurs concurrently some error occurs which ends up prematurely terminating the script.

The fix was to redirect the output to the SD card and then us `cp` to copy it to the USB drive:

```
product-manifest.sh > "/tmp/MANIFEST"
cp "/tmp/MANIFEST" "$1"
```

Thanks to @mikeserv for pointing me in the right direction.